# Keep create and update methods separate or use them together?

Tags: c#

Title is rather vague, I wasn't sure how to work is.

I'm attempting at improving my professionalism when it comes to developing, and I'm not sure how to go about structuring the flow within one of my classes.

I'm building a product inventory system that holds various details about products i.e. name, size, quantity and cost.

I have a class `InventorySystem` which makes calls to `ProductDatabase`, it is the second class where all of my CRUD functionality will be stored.

`InventorySystem` has the methods `CreateProduct()` and `UpdateProduct()` which will call upon the database to perform CRUD methods according to whatever is required. My problem is that within the database class I don't know whether to keep these methods separate, or to first use a helper method `productExists()` to first check whether the product exists in the table.

What I mean is, which of the following would be best practice.

```
public int decideAction(Product p)
        {
            bool productExists = productExistsInMap(p);

            if(productExists)
            {
                UpdateProduct(p);
            }
            else
            {
                AddProduct(p);
            }
        }
```

In this method the `productExistsInMap()` method is used to determine whether or not the passed object already exists in the map, if it does, then the existing product entry is updated, if not it is added to the map.

Or

```
public int AddProduct(Product p)
{
    string productName = p.ProductName;

    if(productMap.ContainsKey(productName))
    {
        return "item already exists in map";
    }
    else
    {
        productMap.Add(productName, p);
        return 2;
    }
}
```

In this method the `productExistsInMap()` method is not used, and instead checking the map for an existing entry is performed within the method itself. If the product already exists then no update is performed, as there will be a separate `updateProduct` method that exists.

Essentially the difference is whether there should be a method that determines if the map is to be added to or updated and calls the appropriate method, verses two individual methods that perform the add and update that are explicitly called by the `InventorySystem` class.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends IMHO. Sometimes you want to explicitly keep them separate (you don't always want to update an existing item or you don't always want to insert a missing item). IOW you could have methods for Insert(), Update() and also Upsert() which is commonly called and does an insert or update based on existence.

However, you seem to be talking about doing 'Upsert' operation locally, checking its existence in local or remote? If you mean to:

- Check if that exists in backend
- Insert if not or update

It would be an invitation to concurrency problems. You should do both the check and insert or update in the backend atomically.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean about `Upsert` being used locally. All of the CRUD methods, including the method that checks existence are incorporated into the `ProductDatabase` class. The project itself is just a rudimentary application, it doesn't have an actual backend it's just a small C# program I'm writing to sharpen my C# skills.

Comment: OK, think of it, where is the data itself? If in memory, then it wouldn't matter, no one else is inserting or updating. Otherwise in a multiuser environment, you might be checking Item Z which is not there and you attempt to insert. Within that very tiny time frame (say 1ms) you make your check, somebody else might have inserted Item Z.